# Django oracle its not working

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle, django-oracle

I already install oracle client 12.2 also i installed pip instal cx_Oracle but this error seeing. I given my database connection settings to settings.py im sure its completely true but whats the error exactly mean ?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
web_1  |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
web_1  |     return self._cursor()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
web_1  |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 212, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     return Database.connect(self._connect_string(), **conn_params)
web_1  | django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
```

Comment: The error is a configuration error. Did you install the compatible versions of Oracle client, cx_python, etc? Have you edited `path`? Have you rebooted? There's [all sorts of things which could cause this error](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/55https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/55). You must debug your environment with a precise eye.

Comment: Yes i install Oracle client 12.2 and i also install cx_Oracle. But i just wanna connect another oracle db server not in my local so it is necessary to install oracle client ? Also how can i edit my path and what it should be ?

Comment: Follow the instructions provided in the link referenced by the error message.